# Apple Remote Desktop Shutdown

Tags: terminal, applescript, remote-desktop, shutdown

I am relatively new to Macs and their osascript syntax. I have a mac mini set up as a server and I am trying to use Apple Remote Desktop to send a command to one of the iMac workstations. When I send the command **osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to shut down'** I get the message **execution error: File permission error (-54)**. I am unsure how to resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm no expert on ARD, but I have a feeling you're hitting Gatekeeper... system prefs>security & privacy>privacy which would need adding on that machine. Do you need to do this by script? There's a menu command under Manage to shut down the remote machine.

Comment: I work in a school where we have a network of iMacs and a Mac Mini server. I need to be able to schedule the imacs power on and power offs from the mac mini server. I have gone to system prefs > security & privacy > privacy but am unsure to what settings is it I need to alter, sorry!

Comment: tbh, it's the kind of thing I'd send to the nearest machine & go look. I don't really know specifically what event it would raise, sorry. Someone's bound to come along later who can tell you more - wish you luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run sudo command with ARD select run command as User and written root.

Edit : It doesn't have to go through the osascript to turn it off. A `shutdown -h now` with root user is enough

You can also shutdown the station via the Manage menu

[image]

Comment: yeah I tried this before using the sudo command which did not work but running as root without the sudo command did the trick, as you pointed out here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule shutdown's and restarts directly from within ARD, no scripting needed.

[image]